# Detox build command fails in Github jobs

Tags: detox

Running build test for ios release locally is working fine, however it fails on Github actions [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0Jlw.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your app build command (that you have provided in Detox config) is faulty and that is why your app is failing build. Unrelated to Detox.

Comment: How is it faulty, I have followed the guide for building the app according to detox documentation, the problem is it can not find a file that is in the project (GoogleServices.plist) should I add a specific command for it to be added to the build

Comment: The build command cannot come from Detox docs. Your build command comes from your own project.